# Synaptics touchpad detected as PS/2 Generic Mouse on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, touchpad, hp, synaptics, dv6

I have just installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my computer (HP pavilion dv6) but I am not able to get work my Synaptics Touchpad.

I launched a xinput -list and I could see that it is installed as PS/2 Generic mouse but unable to get ready to work with a xinput set-prop "Device Enabled" 1

Gsynaptics also fails to detected it, and I followed this steps with out success.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad

Other ubuntu's release also fails and an external mouse works fine. Please help me!! :'(

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem for eight months! For me the only solution was to run the command line:

`$ sudo modprobe -r psmouse; sudo modprobe psmouse`

et voilá, the system recognize the touchpad again. To have a permanently solution, you can write the command above in /etc/rc.local (but without sudo).

Hope it works to you as do for me!